# how do I extract the following values

Tags: rigging

I'm watching Rigging's tutorial. I'm having trouble applying the driver to the transform constrainted  bone. The following words should be included in the path value. I don't know how to extract the following values.

pose.bones["upper_arm.fk.L"]["isolate_rotation"]

[image]

Comment: Unclear what you mean by "extract the value"  Is the constraint being driven  on the same pose bone as the custom property "isolate_rotation" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hover your mouse over the value of your property or custom property and use the right click "Copy data path".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When choosing rig as target object, typically you can select desired bone.

[image: driver]

Be sure your 'rig' object is of 'ARMATURE' type.

Comment: Going by driver in question it is a single property type driver.  The property being a custom property "isolate_rotation" on the pose bone "upper_arm.fk.L"